# Is there any meta to allow https cache?

Tags: html, https, meta-tags, meta

I implemented the https in my webpage but after that I observe in my server logs that the user browser cache stopped.
Can you please let me know if is there any meta to allow https cache in user browser?
I appreciate any help.